# NHibernate Map many-to-many join table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My database structure looks something like this:

```
Person
  Id
  Name
  FieldA
  FieldB

Phone
  Id
  Number

PersonPhone
  PhoneId
  PersonId
  IsDefault
```

My NHibernate mappings for the Person and Phone objects are straight forward, its the PersonPhone I'm having difficult with. I want to have a collection of PersonPhone objects as a property of Person which will allow me to have the Phone number of a person and be able to tell which is the "default" or primary phone number for a person.

ideally Id like my PersonPhone object to look like this:

```
public class PersonPhone
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Phone Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

so far my NHibernate mapping for this table looks like the following:

```
<class name="PersonPhone" table="PersonPhone">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="Person" column="PersonId" />
        <key-property name="Phone" column="PhoneId" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="IsDefault" column="IsDefault"/>
</class>
```

but when NHibernate compiles my mappings I get an error saying:

Could not compile the mapping document: MyApp.Entities.PersonPhone.hbm.xml. NHibernate.MappingException : Could not determine type for: MyApp.Entities.Person, MyApp.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(PersonId)

Any ideas on how this should be mapped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to use the  element in your composite key rather than the key-property

```
<class name="PersonPhone" table="PersonPhone">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="Person" column="PersonId"></key-many-to-one>
        <key-many-to-one name="Phone" column="PhoneId"></key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="IsDefault" column="IsDefault"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think It is more proper to consider Many-to-Many relationship between Phone and Peron entities and get rid of PersonPhone entity.

Comment: without the PersonPhone entity I would have no way of representing the IsDefault property.

Comment: I don't know If it would be right to have many-to-many mapping and an additional property Person.DefaultPhone. The point, I don't like the idea of PersonPhone I usually try to mock/capture entities in live in my design.

Answer (score 3):

To set-up the same mapping with Fluent NHibernate, do this:

```
public class PersonPhoneMap : ClassMap<PersonPhone>
{
    public PersonPhoneMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(p => m.Person)
            .KeyReference(p => m.Phone);

        References(p => p.Person)
            .Column("PersonID");
        References(m => m.Phone)
            .Column("PhoneID");
        Map(p => p.IsDefault)
            .Column("IsDefault");
    }
}
```