# Join tables in NHIbernate

Tags: nhibernate

I asked question in this thread, but nobody answered

[NHibernate Map many-to-many join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881865/nhibernate-map-many-to-many-join-table)

how you can select all Persons with phone number contains 777. I do somthing like this, but it does not work

```
var tags = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
                .CreateAlias("Phone", "p", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .CreateAlias("PersonPhone", "pp", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.Like("p.Name", "777"))
                .List();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var result = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Person))
            .CreateAlias("Phone", "p")
            .Add(Property.ForName("p.Name").Like("777"))
            .List<Person>();
```

I think this might work.